# What is the difference between a N96 and N96e grid space?

Tags: raster, grids-graticules

Global land-use and meteorological raster datasets are often gridded using N96 or N96e grids. I suspect that they are slightly different but I cannot find information on how they differ. Both split the world into 192 x 144 cells. Do they have the same origin (i.e. Greenwich)? How are they defined?